# Google Authenticator on WordPress Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure

i am trying to install google authenticator plugin on wordpress. the issue is that it does not work on wordpress installed on azure citing incompatibility.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-authenticator-per-user-prompt/

could someone please let me know if they have successfully installed the following plugin on wordpress on azure.

```
Google Authenticator - Per User Prompt error: Your environment doesn't meet all of the system requirements listed below.
PHP 5.2.4+ (You're running version 5.4.9)
WordPress 3.5+ (You're running version 3.8)
The Google Authenticator plugin must be installed and activated.
If you need to upgrade your version of PHP you can ask your hosting company for assistance, and if you need help upgrading WordPress you can refer to the Codex.
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Google Authenticator plugin ? http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-authenticator/

Answer (score 0):

If still not solved, try this [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/token2-hardware-tokens/), although it says "hardware tokens", any TOTP App including Google Auth should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress in Azure then you can use choose google, AAD, gmail open id connect in Azure portal.

Webapp -->Authentication option --> choose any open id